# Webview app MIC aceess issue in Android studio

Tags: java

I build a web view app. Its is an online tuition app. So, there is an live video class daily. So need permission to access their microphone.Plz help to get out from this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXiWY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Android 6.0 and above will not have any permissions at installation time. So, you need to ask for permission at run time. Probably, you haven't granted permission for audio recording for the application.
To fix this issue, go to your AndroidManifest.xml file located at /app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and add the following permission.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

You need to add this permission outside the application block.

```
.
.
.
    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iam already added those permission.


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>

and code here.


    if(checkAndRequestPermissions()){
            //all permission granted
        }else{
            //require all permission.
        }

    }


    private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int camerapermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int phonestate = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int location = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int recordaudio = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        int modifyAudio = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        int caputureaudio = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT);
        int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (camerapermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (phonestate != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (location != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (recordaudio != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
        if (modifyAudio != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        }
        if (caputureaudio != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT);
        }

        if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You should have included this in your question when you initially posted, so that we'll know what we're doing